# When applying for a saved job, the application date is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I saved a job several month ago (Apr 2018), and I just applied for it (Sep 2018).

Now I realize the date recorded with the application is wrong. The date corresponding to when I saved the job has been taken into account instead of the application date.

In this case the date should be overridden by the application date right ?

This bug could have a severe impact if the employer also get wrong data, and even worse if SO notification system is based on a cron job tracking recent/new events and if such tracking is based on this [wrong] date (i.e. which would mean that SO will never notify the employer).

Dates below should be the date of today (Sep 5 2018).

[image]
[image]

---

Any idea to workaround the issue for now (I just need my application to be *sent on time* for this position) ?

---

Can someone have a look at it and fix it quickly or does it need further investigation ?

Comment: Seems a bug for me too... or at least bad UI/UX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Please note that the bug only impacted the messaging interface.